# retrieve POM version and display on the frontend

Tags: javascript, html, pom.xml, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I have a POM file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.jira.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-service</artifactId>
    <version> ${POM_JIRAVERSION}-${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I've got an HTML page where I want to display my POM version number, my version number is dynamic as you can see and changes with every build I make on Jenkins. How can I retrieve the version from the POM.xml and display it on my HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using PluginVersionImpl from Atlassian API.

Check out this link:
[PluginVersionImpl](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.1.1/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/PluginVersionImpl.html)

Inject PluginVersionImpl to your code:

```
PluginVersionImpl pluginVersionImpl;
```

Use method to get plugin version:

```
String version = pluginVersionImpl.getVersion();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31443468)